# Find Data Between Dates and Copy Them to New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a report feature for a machine downtime tracker I have created for work. I have a userform which asks for the machine name, as well as the date range they would like to get data from. I would like this to open the workbook where the data is stored, capture the data they want and copy it to a new workbook.

After searching on here for a while I was able to put something together with the autofilter feature, but I cannot get any of the data to show up on the new sheet. I think it may have something to do with the Date, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
Public Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("FILEPATH")


'~~> Checks to see what sheet the data should be copied from based on the combo box entry.
If Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine1" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine1")
ElseIf Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine2" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine2")
ElseIf Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine3" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine3")
ElseIf Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine4" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine4")
ElseIf Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine5" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine5")
ElseIf Me.cmboWorkCenter.Value = "Machine6" Then
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Machine6")
Else
    MsgBox "ERROR"
    Unload Me
End If

startDate = Me.txtStartTime.Value
endDate = Me.txtEndTime.Value


With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("B1:B" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
        Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    ''~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

'~~> Destination File
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lRow = 1
    End If

    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

wb1.Close


End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working solely with column B, specifically .Range("B1:B" & lRow). The field isn't 2 it is 1 since there is only one column in .Range("B1:B" & lRow).

```
With .Range("B1:B" & lRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
    Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
End With
```

Comment: Now possibly another question... That works fine for me if the date in the data sheet is in the YYYY-MM-DD format. But if I include the time in the data now the filter no longer works. Do you know how I would change my code so it would work for datetime?